# What causes the creation of a Vue component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I've implemented component routing based on data returned from a server page held in a CMS. Summary - on a route change the path is sent to the server which returns a template name and data for that template. The template name maps to a component name which then uses the data. The issue I am seeing is that after I change the routing, while the target component is created and displayed, the original component (source route) is also created twice.

Here's the code that fetches data from the server and uses it to set the new route.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!app) {
    next()
    return
  }
  // get page data from the server.
  app.$store.dispatch('getPageData', to.fullPath).then(r => {
    // check whether vue-router knows this route
    // if not then map it to the right component
    if (to.matched.length === 0) {
      let component = mapTemplate(r.data.page.template)
      // add the route (undocumented but intentionally released)
      router.addRoutes([{path: to.path, component}])
      // change to the same route now that vue-router knows it
      next(to.fullPath)
      return
    }
    next()
  })
})
```

Now the (abridged) console log. The sequence captured in the log is:

1. load '/' which uses template `p-home.vue`.
2. navigate using menu to /ready-to-wear/ which uses component `p-rtw-products`

The **bold** lines show `p-home` lifecycle hooks. The *italic* line shows when `vue-router` is done with the routing. The line that says "setting route" displays the new route that was added to the router.

```
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home created
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home mounted
lmd-app.vue?70d9:48 fetchdata for /
index.js?3672:62 router.beforeEach() / => /ready-to-wear/
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home destroyed
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home created
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home mounted
index.js?3672:73 beforeEach() setting route /ready-to-wear/ target: PRtwProducts
index.js?3672:62 router.beforeEach() / => /ready-to-wear/
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home destroyed
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home created
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home mounted
index.js?3672:77 router.afterEach()
p-rtw-products.vue?5a57:22 p-rtw-products created
p-home.vue?1e58:54 p-home destroyed
p-rtw-products.vue?5a57:25 p-rtw-products mounted
```

OK, thanks for all that have gotten this far. I'd expect one create-destroy sequence for `p-home` yet there are three. I can even imagine that because it was the original source of the route that creating it was already queued (though I don't really believe it).

Does anyone know why it is behaving as it does?

Comment: A couple notes: the final result gets the right data with the right component but I'd like to understand the unexplained behavior (I wouldn't notice unless I'd logged lifecycle hooks). And the code and log above are edited to keep them to better focused. Please let me know if there are any errors.

Comment: Are your components separate or 'p-rtw-products' is inside 'p-home.vue' somehow? In other words, where 'router-view' is called - inside 'p-home' or inside an outer wrapper?

Comment: The structure is that there is a generic page (`c-standard-page`) that each `p-` page uses. `c-standard-page` has a header, footer, and a slot for the `p- component`s' specific content. each `p-` and `c-` component is implemented as a separate `.vue` file. Short version, no `p-rtw-products` is not (unless I'm missing something obvious) inside `p-home.vue`.